# How to add funtionallity to a Jbutton,located in superclass from a subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to add functionality to a Jbutton using subclass butt Jbutton is actually declared and defined in super class.
Here is my code:

```
 JButton zz=new JButton(ss);
         zz.setBounds(470,70,35,35);
         zz.setBorder(oo);
         zz.setBackground(new Color(0,170,120));
         l.add(zz);
```

This is my Jbutton located in super class named as realestate in my project.I have created subclass in which i am trying to add action listener for this button.
Here is my subclass:

```
public class assan extends RealEstate{
zz.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent u)
   {
       System.out.println("kk");
   }
});}
```

butt i run this program i got different types of errors such as:
`Package 'zz' does not exist` etc.
This is my full code:

```
 package realestate;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Realestate extends JFrame {
 Realestate()
 {
    JLabel l=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD SHAHAB\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Real Estate\\src\\real\\estate\\file (2).jpg"));
                   l.setBounds(100,50,300,250);
                   add(l); 
                    ImageIcon ss=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD SHAHAB\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Real Estate\\src\\real\\estate\\1470672145_Help_mark_query_question_support_talk.png");
                public  JButton zz=new JButton(ss);
             zz.setBounds(470,70,35,35);
             zz.setBackground(new Color(0,170,120));
             l.add(zz);
 }
    public class assan extends Realestate{
        zz.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent o)
           {
               System.out.println("Cena");
           }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      RealEstate v=new RealEstate();
         v.setUndecorated(true);
         v.setVisible(true);
         v.setBounds(350,200,600,350);
         v.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
assan n=new assan();
    }

}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Provide the full code.The above doesn't even compile.

Comment: ok wait a min GoX

Comment: You have several option: make sure `zz` is visible to the subclass ('public` , `protected` or package visible `field` OR add a getter to the super class.

Comment: This is my full code:

Comment: c0der as you can see in my code i have written public with the super class realestate

Comment: Please post an [MCVE]. This code does not compile, and I assume you can demonstrate the problem in a much shorter code

Comment: c0der  wait a minute

Comment: @Mcolo Consider using some kind of IDE for formatting the code and checking if it works before posting it.

Comment: @c0der i am still getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Put the following class in the file `RealState.java`:

  ```
  public class RealEstate extends JFrame {

      protected JButton zz = null;

      RealEstate() {
          JLabel l = new JLabel("Label");
          l.setBounds(100, 50, 300, 250);
          add(l);

          // ImageIcon ss = new ImageIcon("path_to_image_file");
          zz = new JButton("MyButton");
          zz.setBounds(470, 70, 35, 35);
          zz.setBackground(new Color(0, 170, 120));
          add(zz); 
      }
  }
  ```
- And put the subclass in its own file too: `Assan.java`

  ```
  public class Assan extends RealEstate {

      public Assan() {
          zz.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent o)   {
                 System.out.println("Cena");
             }
          });
      }


      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Assan v = new Assan();
          v.setUndecorated(true);
          v.setVisible(true);
          v.setBounds(350, 200, 600, 350);
          v.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      }
  }
  ```

Note that I have made two changes:

- make the variable you want to modify in the subclass `protected`
- move the main method to the subclass if you want the event handler to be executed.
- And lastly, you have to follow some tutorials, for example

  1. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) you will learn about inheritance
  2. [Java Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

> Imagine that this is the **superclass**:

```
public class RealEstate{
    public JButton button = new JButton("Button Name");
}
```

> And this the **subclass**:

```
public class SubClass extends RealEstate{

   /**
   * Constructor
   */
   public SubClass(){

       //The Button is public so it is visible to the subclass
       button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent u){
                 System.out.println("Hello World!");
              }
       });
   }  
}
```

Also have a look at this ([tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm))

> A minimal example of the code you may need:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class RealEstate extends JFrame {

    public JButton button = new JButton("Button");

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public RealEstate() {


  //Button
       button.setText("I am a JButton");

        // ...rest of the code below
    }

    /**
     * The SubClass
     */
    protected class SubClass extends RealEstate {

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public SubClass() {

            //accessing the button from the SubClass
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent u) {
                    System.out.println("Hello World!");
                }
            });
        }

    }

    /**
     * Main Method
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RealEstate v = new RealEstate();
        v.setUndecorated(true);
        v.setVisible(true);
        v.setSize(600,600);
        v.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        v.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: GoXR3Plus when i wrote public with Jbutton it's giving me error:'illegal start of expression'

Comment: What is the meaning / purpose to `l.add(button)` ?

Comment: @Mcolo I edited the code.Although it needs and a layout to work properly.I will provide a full example when i get back to computer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following and read the comments carefully. The code is meant not only to highlight some errors, but also demonstrate the idea of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

//Java is case sensetive. You can't call a class Realestate
//and later use RealEstate v= new RealEstate();
public class RealEstate /*Realestate*/ extends JFrame {

    //to make zz visible to other classes it should be a field
    public JButton zz;

    RealEstate()
    {
        //remove what is not needed to demonstrate the problem, remove it
        //JLabel l
        //ImageIcon ss=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD SHAHAB\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Real Estate\\src\\real\\estate\\1470672145_Help_mark_query_question_support_talk.png");

        //wrong
        //public JButton zz=new JButton("Button");
        zz=new JButton("Button");
        zz.setBounds(470,70,35,35);
        zz.setBackground(new Color(0,170,120));

        add(zz);
        //you can't add a button to a JLabel
        //l.add(zz);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RealEstate v= new RealEstate();
        v.setUndecorated(true);
        v.setVisible(true);
        v.setBounds(350,200,600,350);
        v.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        Assan n= new Assan();
    }
}

//Use right naming convention. Assan and not assan
class Assan extends RealEstate{

    //this code has to be enclosed in a constructor
    //or a method
    //zz.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    //  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent o)
    //  {
    //      System.out.println("Cena");
    //  }
    //});

    Assan(){

        zz.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent o)
            {
                System.out.println("Cena");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i have run the above code butt i am getting 'Null pointer exception in main'.

Comment: I am still getting the same exception.